# How to serialize tensorflow tensor as raw byte string

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get tensorflow to write a tensor to something that would be ingestible by ffmpeg (e.g. PCM 32-bit floating-point little-endian). I'm not seeing a simple way to do this. `tf.io.serialize_tensor` seems to transform to TensorProto proto.

I can't use `tensorflow-io` because this needs to work in `tensorflow-serving`. `tf.audio.write_wav` doesn't work because it only supports a bit-depth of int16 and I need float32.

I'd like something like:

```py
serialized_foo = magic_encoding(foo)  # foo is a tensor of type float32 and serialized_foo is a string
tf.io.write_file("foo.raw", serialized_foo)
```

It seems like `tf.io.serialize_tensor` gets part of the way there. From what I can tell quickly inspecting the file, the protobuf format appears to be the raw byte string plus some sort of short header? Would it be possible just to modify the output of `tf.io.serialize_tensor` slightly, dropping the header?

Comment: Have you tried pickle?

Comment: tensorflow can't pickle objects

Comment: This is tensorflow... have you tried `tensor.numpy()` then serialize that? Alternatively, reading the source code can probably do something...

Comment: This is for tensorflow-serving so it has to be in graph mode, i.e. no .numpy() allowed. The source code is all in c++, so no easy workaround in python that I can find :(